# Do I push the solution or just what I changed?

Tags: c++, git, github, solution

I changed one file in my project, `LoginLogout.cpp`. What should I be pushing if all I changed was `LoginLogout.cpp`? Do I need to re-push the solution also?

Comment: You check in the change to your local active branch that you cloned from the server, and then you push the entire branch to the server. Only delta changes between checkins will actually be stored.

Answer (score 0):

If all you changed is `LoginLogout.cpp`, then you only need to add that file to your new commit by doing `git add LoginLogout.cpp`. This will only add that file to your staging area, which you can then commit with `git commit -m "changed LoginLogout.cpp"` for example.

After that you just need to push this commit to your repo with `git push` which uploads all local branch commits to the corresponding remote branch.